# Google sheets: Is it possible to have a chart automatically update each day based on the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to create a line chart in Google Sheets that automatically updates every day to show a value in a specific cell.

For example, I have an accounting value in cell B11 - I want that to be plotted on a chart with the value on the y-axis and today's date in the x-axis. Then tomorrow, that value will update because of currency changes and also because of new revenue. I then want that new value to be added to the line chart with that new date.

Essentially, I want to create a chart that tracks a value over time but with the value to be plotted contained in the same cell each time.

Is this even possible? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The data source for the chart will need to be a range which grows with each new value in B11, so you will need a way of copying the value from B11 into the range at the required interval. Doable using scripts or possibly formulas (with iterative calculation turned on).